# C# serial data interpretation

Tags: c#, serial-port

How to convert data received from serial port

I have a metal stripe measurement machine from which I import data into a C# application using the RS232 port. The situation is like this:

the machine has no documentation, so, after playing with a bunch of combinations of baud rates, stop bits and parity I've managed to import the correct value from the machine, but the value is extracted like this:
`11+myvalue` or `11-myvalue` where the sign (`+` or `-`) is correct, my value is correct excepting the fact that it should be `float`.

```
    mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
    mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
    mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
    mySerialPort.DataBits = 7;
    mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
    mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
    mySerialPort.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("Connection was successfully established.");
}


private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;

    indata = sp.ReadExisting();
    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(displaydata_event));
}
```

Example of correct values:
should be: `+5.23` or `-12.52`
but I receive: `11+523` or `11-1252`

How can I get rid of that "`11`" and obtain the correct value.

Comment: What is the text-encoding being used?

Comment: It's hard to tell without documentation, but what I would _guess_ is this: 1. The machine is just omitting the decimal dot, and you just need to do n / 100 to get that float value. 2. "11" is some kind of message code that's (hopefully) part of some protocol. Maybe try and change some settings on the machine and see if the output changes with it. If it stays the same: just cut it off.

Comment: I looked at the little-endian bit representation of 7-bit ASCII `+5.23` and compared it to `11+523` and I can't see any obvious reasons they might be getting confused - so I'm siding with @Fildor in that it's probably some undocumented protocol that you need to handle specifically instead of assuming it's actually sending ASCII down the wire.

Comment: Thank you all. It seems I should cut off the "11" by code.

Comment: Not necessarily.  What character terminates the response from the device (or determines the length of the response).  Because the device is constantly sending data and you may not receive all the character in one event and you have to merge receive data into one string. Then flush first message to first valid bit.

Comment: Are you sure the 11 isn't from a previous response?  The `DataReceived` event isn't guaranteed to fire when new characters come in, so its possible you have some from a previous message.  Can you share your `displaydata_event` for us?

Comment: @Baddack that's not possible.I forgot to mention, the reading takes place when I push a pedal.So only the value displayed on the device is readen.To be more specific, the device is made by Imess and it measures the camber edge of a metal strip.Their software doesn't allow us to do much with the data, so we made our custom one.

Comment: If that metal stripe measuring machine is a generalized commercial product, if you add manufacturer and model number information, someone could possibly provide a link to information about the specification and protocol.